# Security in including file even using is_file

Tags: php, security, include, sanitize, whitelist

I learned a lot at Stackoverflow, it's my favorite programming website, and researching here I found the answers for many of my questions.
Now that I've finished the code I need to know: does it have any security flaw?

It needs to get the domain name from the url in order to see if a var file containing that expression exists on the directory and output it's content.
Your help is really appreciated!

Would be enough if I sanitize HTTP_HOST using htmlspecialchars and preg_replace? Using strip_tags would be overkill, no? Removing those special characters from the array is also redundant, don't you think?

**Edit**:

I'll alter the code and also add protection to the include files themselves. Many thanks!

Comment: You should never EVER let any user-provided data get anywhere NEAR an operation that deals with the file system, particularly in something as dangerous as `include`. This wouldn't be easy to exploit, but I'm sure someone could figure out how to do it.

Comment: Why would you check for file existence of a domain name? Are you aware the HTTP_HOST is a user provided var which could contain almost anything?

Comment: This has been a dilemma for me, but I really need to get the domain from HTTP_HOST.
If I could strip not only the domain extensions but also "/" , "." , "=" , ";" etc, wouldn't it solve the problem?

Comment: @echolearning Can't you simply keep a white-list?

Comment: Why not? You can definitely use certain urls, since only the domains you control  will contain the `*var.php` files.

Comment: My issue is the load that check would provoke, it's a big list.

Answer (score 1):

No. You should be using a white-list of allowed expressions. For something as dangerous as `include` you definitely don't want to rely on black-list and simple sanitization.

You would also hardcode which directory contains your PHP files.

Comment: If the white list has thousands of entries wouldn't be very hard on the server?

Comment: wouldn't that mean that you'd have thousands of `*var.php` files? Am I missing something?

Comment: Correct, but they are very simple files and I have Litespeed, opening them isn't a problem, php process time may be, hence my problem. But if there is no alternative to a whitelist...

Comment: I'm just saying: Your collection of `*var.php` files _already is_ a whitelist.

Comment: Going with the whitelist solution, should I create a manual list to be faster and lighter on the server?

Comment: Whitelist doesn't mean to keep a list of each and every file present and allowed. It means you **define what is accepted**, and every thing else is denied by default. Blacklist, on the opposite, **defines what is denied** and the rest is allowed by default (this is what you are doing in your code sample). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist .

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you keep all the `*var.php` files in a special directory (let's say `/var/www/include/vars/`) you could read them into an array, and confine the selection within the boundaries of that array, instead of just `is_file()`ing:

```
$vardir='/var/www/include/vars/';
$varfiles=array();
foreach(scandir($vardir) as $fn)
  if(($fn!='.')&&($fn!='..'))
    $varfiles[]="$vardir$fn";

/* Next, do whatever sanitizing you see fit */

if(array_find($fnvar)) include_once $fnvar;
```

Note that this, essentially, *is* a whitelist, mentioned in the comments: If you create a new `{xyz}var.php` in the `$vardir` directory, you are actually inserting a new entry in the whitelist.

So as @ack__ points out too, you can't avoid a whitelist one way or another...

Comment: Many thanks on the detailed answer. My problem is the processing time/load for that check :/

Comment: Well, your question was security-specific. Should you decide to go this way, I'm sure there would be plenty of optimization techniques at your disposal.

Comment: I really appreciate this.